# External javascript not working?

Tags: javascript

I just started learning javascript about 30 minutes ago. I'm doing an online course and they gave me this code as an example. The person in the video did the exact same thing, but it only works for me when I do inline not external. My .js name is right and they're in the same folder.

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JavaScript Basics</title>    
  <script src=“cripts.js”></script>
 </head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <h1>Where to place your JavaScript code.</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the js:

```
alert("YOU");
```

Nothing appears for me. I've tried everything to make it work, including different browsers. Could it be my computer or did I make a simple mistake?

Comment: So the name is supposed to be `cripts.js`?

Comment: Those are funny quote characters in the `<sctipt` tag line. I believe you copied it from somewhere, and as a beginner it would be helpful if you type manually instead.

Comment: `scripts.js`? (typo)

Comment: You have fancy quotes, those are not valid. `“`

Comment: Copy and pasters conundrum...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your quotes are invalid :') Good beginner move! But it will be a simple fix. Note the ***“*** should be ", this usually happens when copying and pasting code!

```
<script src="cripts.js"></script>
```

Also make sure your path and file name is correct?! cripts.js sounds like it is suppose to be scripts.js

Comment: I rarely see this as a result of c&p, rather of using the wrong editor. Or: not using a code editor but a word processor.

Comment: Either way, they are invalid :D @Bergi - Maybe it's time for the OP to change editors `:“)`

Comment: It often happens in TextEdit on iOS.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote the command in my notes on pages on mac and then copied it. Can't believe I spent all that time for just that. Thank YOU.

Comment: Haha! It happens to the best of us @melkadri

Answer (score 0):

A beginner mistake I made was to use `<script>...</script>` tags in the external javascript file. From HTML if you use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../myApp/myFile.js"></script>
```

Then the external js file should just contain just the code such as:

```
function myFunction {}
```

with no script tags. This is unlike linking to external css files which include the `<style>...</style>` tags.